# Qt 5.3.1 - a dramatic increase in performance

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

Colleagues,

We've got a piece of software that analyzer large amounts of records stored in text files. The most popular library calls are probably file access, QSharedPointer and QString creation and access.

Currently we're using Qt 5.0.2, but the other day I did try to compile the software with Qt 5.3.1. Frankly I was very surprised to see at least 50%-70% increase in speed, without any changes in our code.

Just out of curiosity, does anyone have an idea what might have contributed to such a speed boost ?

My initial idea is that the later is more C++11 optimized, including full support for move constructors, which would allow to save tens of millions of temp object creations.

Comment: Or perhaps the more recent Qt has been compiled with a more recent compiler (and perhaps more optimization flags). Compilers are still improving!

Comment: Do you work for Qt? ;o)

Comment: @Galik I wish ! :)

BasileStarynkevitch Yes, 5.3.1 comes with gcc 4.8.2 and Qt 5.0.2 uses gcc 4.7.2. But I'm not sure if compiler optimizations can give a program such a boost...

Comment: You can profile your application with the old and new versions of Qt to see that is the difference, unless you forgot that you recently upgraded your hardware.

Comment: @vahancho Definitely no new hardware involved :) 
Don't have for proper profiling, unfortunately :( Software is Windows-only at the moment, and in Windows it's not that easy to profile MinGW-based software, gprof is not very user friendly.

Comment: @Vlad: Without profiling and code, it is unlikely anyone can give you an answer, not even a guessed one.

Comment: I'm a bit suspicious of the reported results -- given the incredible speed of CPUs these days (relative to storage media), code that reads from the filesystem is usually I/O bound, and so making the code more CPU efficient typically doesn't result in a measurable speedup.  My guess as to an explanation:  when you tested 5.0.2, most or all of the data set had to be read from the hard drive, which is slow.  Then when you tested with 5.3.1, most or all of the data set was still cached in RAM (from before), and thus the program never had to wait for the hard disk --> fast :)

Comment: Did you test debug vs release by accident?

Comment: Definitely both release versions and don't think any disk cache was involved. I did 3 runs for version one then 3 runs for version 2 and repeated the sequence multiple times - results are consistent.

I'm really curious myself what could contribute that much. Will run more isolated tests next week and will comment here when I know the reason.